# NPVariant to string array

Tags: npapi

I would like to pass an array of strings to a NPAPI plugin. How do I convert [NPVariant](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/NPVariant) to an array of strings?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like you're going the other diretction from what jldupont suggested.  When you pass an array in as a parameters to either a property or a method:

```
var arrayData = [1,2,3,4,5];
plugin.someProperty = arrayData;
// -or-
plugin.callSomeMethod(arrayData);
```

That parameter will get to your NPObject as a NPVariant of type NPVariantType_Object.  You then query the length property:

```
NPObject *inObject = val->value.objectValue;
NPVariant npvLength;
NPN_GetProperty(npp, inObject, NPN_GetStringIdentifier("length"), &npvLength);
```

and then you just do a for loop to get all the values:

```
for (uint32_t i = 0; i < npvLength.value.intValue; i++) {
    NPVariant curValue;
    NPN_GetProperty(npp, inObject, NPN_GetIntIdentifier(i), &curValue);
    // Do something with curValue
}
```

Similarly, if you need to return an array to javascript, another option (other than writing a method to emulate an object, as I suggested in the thread that jldupont linked to) is to use NPN_GetValue to get the NPObject for the DOM window, and then Invoke "Array" on it with no parameters.  This will return an empty JS Array object (as an NPObject*).  Then you just loop through the items you want to return and call "push" with the item as the first (and only) parameter.

Hope this helps

Comment: Incidently, the open source project FireBreath (http://firebreath.googlecode.com) takes care of all of this stuff for you, plus providing an abstraction so that it will work on IE as well.  (I am one of the primary maintainers of FireBreath)

Answer (score 2):

You can use an NPObject (see this [thread](http://groups.google.com/group/mozilla.dev.tech.plugins/browse_thread/thread/70bfc090f64a86d2)) to act as a container for your strings (much like a JS object with `var arrayOfString={...strings here...}`.

Comment: I wanted to go the other way; from JS to the plugin. Thanks for the input though, it gave me very useful clues.