# How to capture onload, onerror in NPAPI Plugin

Tags: npapi

In javascript my code will be as follows:

```
function start() {  

  var start = document.getElementById('start'); //start is object for my plugin
  if(start){
    getAsLoad(start);
  }
} 
function getAsLoad(startObj) {
var load = startObj.startMethod();

  // Handle progress, success, and errors
  load.onload = loaded;
  load.onerror = errorHandler;
}

function loaded(evt) {  
  var StringData = evt.target.result;
  alert(StringData);      
} // Like loaded similar code for errorHandling
```

How to start it in plain NPAPI Plugin , the event handling mechanism , I know in firebreadth it is a cakewalk , as per my requirement i  can't use it. so this kind of thing i have to implement in NPAPI Plugin. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do it would be to have javascript call your plugin.

If you want to do it from the plugin, though, you just get the DOM window NPObject and start Invoking methods and getting properties, etc.

For example, to get "start" you could call getProperty with "document", then call Invoke on the resulting NPObject with "getElementById" and "start" as the parameter.

The tricky part comes up if you want a callback into your plugin, in which case you'll have to create an NPObject that handles InvokeDefault which is what will be called when the callback fires.  It's a bit of a pain, but from there the details are the same as javascript, just a little more cumbersome

Comment: taxilian as u explained , is there any code sample  to implement in NPAPI or any useful link .

Comment: Basically it's the same technique used in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12078250/return-array-from-npapi-plugin-to-java-script

Comment: I got it taxilian , my only concern is load.onload=loaded;load.onerror = errorHandler; onload property i'll have to define in my plugin, after getting property onload do i have to call NPN_InvokeDefault on a NPObject  or other things as right side is loaded function. load.onload =loaded ; will work.

Comment: you have to provide a npobject that the browser will call NPN_InvokeDefault on; that npobject should be used for "loaded". then you just use SetProperty on the load to set "onload" to that npobject

Comment: I am using setProperty on the load to set "onload". If the name is different than onload .It works fine , but when i set the onload i get null in javascript.